# Get previous and next custom post by custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I try to get previous and next post so I do this :

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'event',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        //'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'meta_key'       => '_start_at',
        'meta_type'      => 'DATETIME',
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But when I look at the list it does not matching with my posts... I have an event in february, next in august, next in march...
How can I do ?
Thandks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the orderby value to meta_value_datetime. More info at WordPress: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

Try this:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'event',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'meta_key'       => '_start_at',
        'meta_type'      => 'DATETIME',
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value_datetime',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Maybe there's an issue with the date value formatting. You could also try removing the meta_type:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'event',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'meta_key'       => '_start_at',
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: It does not work : it is order by published date not by start_at date... I don't understand why It does not work